# How to pass an array from inside a loop to outside the loop in java

Tags: java, arrays, scope

So I was playing around with this program shown below and I want to know how I can modify elements of an array within a loop and then pass on that same modified array outside of the loop (as shown by `numbers2[count] = numbers4[l]`). When I run this code segment, the `max(numbers2)` refers to the array I've instantiated in the beginning and not the modified array from the if statement. Knowing that the scope of an object/variable within a loop is only visible within the loop, how would I go about doing so? Please pertain answers to this code segment below. (`Numbers4` is a string array of length 7 and `numbers2` is a string array of length 3). For example, if I had an array [9, 7, 10] in the array numbers2 and then another array [3, 8, 4, 5, 6, 4, 9] in the array number4 and I wanted to store the 3 from numbers4 into the 1st index of numbers2, resulting in [9, 3, 10], would my if statement pass this specific array, or would it pass [9, 7, 10]?

```
              for(int l = 0; l < numbers4.length; l++) {
                int maxNum2 = max(numbers2);
                if(l % 2 == 0 && l < numbers4.length - 1) {
                    numbers2[count] = numbers4[l];
                    maxNum2 = max(numbers2);
                    int card = Integer.parseInt(numbers4[l + 1]);
                    if(card == 10) {
                        total = total - 10;
                    }else if(card == 11) {
                        total = total + 11;
                    }else if(card == 12) {
                        total = total + 12;
                    }else if(card == 13) {
                        total = total + 13;
                    }else if(card == 14) {
                        if(total < 86) {
                            total = total + 14;
                        }else {
                            total = total + 1;
                        }
                    }else if(card == 9) {
                        total = total + 0;
                    }else {
                        total = total + card;
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

By doing `numbers2[count] = numbers4[l]` you are actually modifying your `numbers2` array, so you don't need to pass it outside the loop

Comment: So if I had an array [9, 7, 10] in the array numbers2 and then another array [3, 8, 4, 5, 6, 4, 9] in the array number4 and I wanted to store the 3 from numbers4 into the 1st index of numbers2, resulting in [9, 3, 10], would my if statement pass this specific array, or would it pass [9, 7, 10]?

Comment: `numbers2` is a reference to your array, so wherever you call `numbers2[count] = something` you modify that array. It doesn't depend on block: as @Josh mentioned, if your variable is declared outside the block, you have access to it from all the nested blocks

Answer (score 0):

The scope of a variable depends on its declaration. If you declare an Array variable outside a loop and mutate it within the loop, then it will be visible in the outer scope. A new variable is not created in the inner scope.

Since numbers2 and numbers4 are not declared inside the loop, they must be declared in an outer scope. So your mutation of Array elements will be visible in that scope.

Comment: So if I had an array [9, 7, 10] in the array numbers2 and then another array [3, 8, 4, 5, 6, 4, 9] in the array number4 and I wanted to store the 3 from numbers4 into the 1st index of numbers2, resulting in [9, 3, 10], would my if statement pass this specific array, or would it pass [9, 7, 10]?

Comment: It would mutate the contents of the array. At the end the value of numbers2 in the scope it was declared would be [9, 3, 10].

Comment: But after the program iterates through the for loop after numbers2 was modified, when it calls int maxNum2 = max(numbers2); , wouldn't it refer to the original instantiated array?

Comment: You are mutating the array. If I have a set of drawers, I can change what is in the drawers, and they are still the same original set of drawers, but the contents are different.